# What are the differences between the 1st and 2nd editions of Galaxy Trucker?

Tags: edition-comparison, galaxy-trucker

What are the differences between the two editions of galaxy trucker and are the expansions compatible with either version?

Answer (score 1):

Consensus at [BoardGameGeek](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/359776/differences-between-1st-and-2nd-edition) seems to be:

> My impression from all of the people who have actually commented after receiving the expansion is that one can play just fine with the original base game as long as one is willing to tolerate some minor inconsistencies.

Apparently the size of cards differ between 1st ed and the expansions, but that can be remedied by sleeving the cards. There are a few inconsistencies in rules texts, but overall 1st ed seems playable with the expansions.